# Prove that a Cauchy sequence in $L^2(X,F,\mu )$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^1(X,F, \mu )$ too?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Suppose $X$ is a measurable space with $\mu$ the measure and $\mu (X) < \infty$ .

If ${f_n}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $L^2(X,F,\mu)$, then is it a Cauchy sequence in $L^1(X,F,\mu)$ too?

I know that since $\mu(X)<\infty$ we have $L^2(X,F,\mu)\subseteq L^1(X,F,\mu) $.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Suppose $f_{n}$ is Cauchy in $L^{2}$. Then, by Holder's inequality and the fact that $\mu(X)<\infty$,

$$
\|f_{n}-f_{m}\|_{1}\leq \|f_{n}-f_{m}\|_{2}\|1_{X}\|_{2}=\|f_{n}-f_{m}\|_2\mu(X)^{1/2}\to 0\quad\text{ as }n,m\to\infty.
$$